# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' in linnworks

Tags: c#, return

I am stuck with one line on my script and keep getting cannot implicitly convert type string to int on line 48 return shipping, I am not quite sure why it is going wrong but just trying to retrieve to check for the shipping text to see if it says UK Next

```
namespace linnworks.finaware.CommonData.Objects                // leave untouched                            
{                                                                                               // leave untouched                            
public class ScriptMacroClass : linnworks.scripting.core.IOrderScript                       // leave untouched                            
    {                                                                                       // leave untouched                            
        public void Initialize(linnworks.finaware.CommonData.Objects.Order order,linnworks.scripting.core.Debugger debug)           // leave untouched                            
        {                                                                                   // leave untouched                            
             }

public int getShipping(linnworks.finaware.CommonData.Objects.Order order)
{

string xml = "";
string shipping = "";


string query = @"
Select ox.ObjectXml
FROM [Order] o
INNER JOIN OrderXml ox ON ox.fkOrderId = o.pkOrderID
WHERE o.pkOrderID = @OrderID
";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(order.GetConnectionString))
{

conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", order.pkOrderID);

using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{

//loop over XML to find the nodes we want
while (reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderWithItems"))
{ //root node
while (reader.ReadToFollowing("ShipServiceLevel"))
{ // buyer node with child elements
{ //the node we want, get it as an string
shipping = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
}
}
}

conn.Close();

}

return shipping;

if (shipping == "UK Next")
{
order.Marker = 2;
order.Save(0);
}


            }                                                                                   // leave untouched                            

            public string Filter(){                                                      // leave untouched                            
                /*Optional: Specify your order filter in query variable, must be SQL Statement that outputs pkOrderId column ONLY*/
                string query="";
                return query;
            }                  

     }                                                                                           // leave untouched                            
}
```

Comment: Sure this `return shipping;` won't work, since the function is expected to return an `int`, change the return type of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `getShipping` function defined as returning an `int` and in fact, `return`ing a `string` even before your function ends. In fact, the function will cease execution on `return` and that part of your code will never execute:

```
if (shipping == "UK Next")
{
order.Marker = 2;
order.Save(0);
}
```

You should check if you even should return an `int`, because I see that code is not even operating on integers.